# How to find the smallest root

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I have a continuous, differentiable, monotonic, bounded function called `F[t]`. If `t -> Infinity` then `F[t] -> c`. I know `c`, and I want to find the smallest `t` value called `t*`, that suffices `F[t]=c` (I am sure there is one).

Could somebody give me some hints about which functions to use for this task? Since I am afraid that `FindRoot` does not work in this case, because even if I know that there is a given `T` that `T` is smaller than `t*`, starting `FindRoot` from `T` as center won't give me the nearest solution, only a solution somewhere near `T` (Or am I wrong?). And neither does Solve work, because `F[t]` is not injective.

Comment: Is there any way to share the function `F[t]`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. For a monotonic, continuous, differentiable function F with supremum c all values F[t] are less then c. Or am I missing something? Could you show the definition of F?

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld See an example of monotonic, continuous, differentiable function F in my answer.

Comment: @Artes Ok that is what we call a "weak" monotonic function.

Comment: I must agree with with the comment of tkott; it sure would be nice to know the function or at least to have some details.  Is it piecewise algebraic (like Artes' example)?  Is it transcendental?  Does it come from a numerical procedure?  These things affect potential solutions.

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld In fact, for strongly monotonic functions we cannot expect solutions as the OP wanted.

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld Well, I supposed that my function had been only monotonic, and not strictly monotonic, and that is why I thought there were no contradictions in my questions. But after your comment I thought it over again, and I realized that you were right, and the function is strictly monotonic. That is my problem is now a simple one, because I will only choose an epsilon that suits my purposes. And it was an interpolating function, so I should have had to suspect, that it cannot be simply monotonic, as Mark McClure mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Briefly, one can use  :

```
Reduce[ D[ F[x], x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

or if the function is not strictly monotonic one should select the maximal element out of the result in the boolean form, e.g.

```
Max @ (( List @@ Reduce[ D[ F[x], x] == 0, x, Reals] // Quiet)[[All, 2]])
```

The major problem is to provide some examples to demonstrate how it works. Since there have been none I will give the following :

**Ex. 1. a class of $C^{1}$ functions**

We define a family of differentiable i.e. $C^{1}$ functions `F` numbered with an `eps` parameter  :

```
P[x_] := a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d
W[x_, eps_] := P[x] //. Flatten @ Solve[{ #^2 == P[#], 1 == P[1], 2 # == P'[#], 1 == P'[1]}, 
                                        {a, b, c, d}]& @ (1 - eps)
Z[x_, eps_] := P[x] //. Flatten @ Solve[{ # == P[#], 2 == P[2], 1 == P'[#], 0 == P'[2]},
                                        {a, b, c, d}]& @ (2 - eps)
F[x_, eps_] := Piecewise[{ { x^2, 0 < x < 1 - eps}, 
                           { W[x, eps], 1 - eps <= x < 1}, 
                           { x, 1 <= x < 2 - eps}, 
                           { Z[x, eps], 2 - eps <= x < 2},
                           { 2, x >= 2} } ]
```

This definition is slightly involved because it is constructed with a few pieces of differentiable functions. The result fulfills the requirements. We introduced auxiliary functions `P`, `W` and `Z`  to define `F` (monotonic, differentiable, and constant after `x` exceeds a certain point `x0`, (here `x0 == 2`)).
Now we can test the result for any `eps` (every `eps > 0` define a differentiable function `F[x, eps]` ), e.g.

```
 Manipulate[ Plot[ F[x, eps], {x, 0, 2.3}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.3}] // Quiet, {eps, 0, 1}]
```

or showing a graph of `F[x, eps]` with a running parameter `eps` on the background of graphs for various `eps` :

```
    Animate[ 
        Show[ Plot[ Evaluate @ Table[ F[x, ep], {ep, 0, 1, 0.1}], {x, 0, 2.3}, 
                    PlotRange -> {0, 2.1}, ImageSize -> {650, 450}] // Quiet, 
              Plot[ F[x, eps], {x, 0, 2.3}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.1}, 
                    PlotStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> {650, 450}] // Quiet, 
              Graphics[{ PointSize[0.015], Magenta,
                         Point @ {{1 - eps, F[1 - eps, eps]}, {2 - eps, F[2 - eps, eps]}}}]
            ],  {eps, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Reduce[ D[F[x, 0.4], x] == 0, x, Reals] // Quiet
Max @ ( List @@ Reduce[ D[ F[x, 0.4], x] == 0, x, Reals] // Quiet)[[All, 2]]
```

> ```
>  x <= 0 || x > 2.
>  2.
> ```

The answer is `x == 2`.

**Edit**

We would like to test the method when the interesting point changes its location, therefore we add another class of functions to demonstrate the reliability of the approach based on `Reduce`.

**Ex. 2. a class of $C^{\infty}$ functions**

We construct a family of `G` functions numbered with an `eps` parameter, but this family is smooth (i.e. $C^{\infty}$) and the gluing point `x == x0` is movable :

```
G[x_, eps_] := 
    Piecewise[{ {1 - eps^2/10 - eps Exp[-(1/(1 - 1/eps - x))], x < 1 - 1/eps},
                {1 - eps^2/10, x >= 1 - 1/eps} }]
```

This family of functions `G` is not analytic of course, (precisely, the only point where the functions are not analytic is `x == 1 - 1/eps`), however they  are still smooth, i.e. we can find their derivatives of any order in `x == 1 - 1/eps`, for any `eps`, e.g.

```
Limit[ Table[ D[G[x, eps], {x, n}], {n, 1, 10}], x -> 1 - 1/eps, Direction ->  1]
Limit[ Table[ D[G[x, eps], {x, n}], {n, 1, 10}], x -> 1 - 1/eps, Direction -> -1]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

thus its expansion in a Taylor series around `x0 == 1 - 1/eps` is constant  unlike the function itself for `x <= x0`.

We can test that for any `eps` we get the correct result :

```
Manipulate[{Reduce[ D[ G[x, eps], x] == 0, x] // Quiet, 1 - 1/eps}, {eps, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image]

and we make a plot of a few functions :

```
GraphicsColumn[
    {Plot[ Evaluate @ Table[ G[x, eps], {eps, 0.2, 1.1, 0.1}], {x, -5, 2}, 
           PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], 

     Plot[ Evaluate @ Table[ G[x, eps], {eps, 0.5, 0.9, 0.1}], {x, -5, 2},  
           PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 0.1}, {0.9, 0.98}}, 
           PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 8]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Terrific! Thank you, Artes! I think I got my answer. But, to tell you the truth, I have missed sg indeed, and so my function is unfortunately strictly monotonic. Your construction is simply brilliant.

Comment: @Rieux I added another example of functions to demonstrate that the approach with `Reduce` is sufficient for the task in the question.